# Access button in _Layout from another View

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio, razor

I have a layout and a view . _Layout.cshtml and Index.cshtml . Is there a way to access the onClick event of a button inside the Layout from the Index view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write event

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){})
```

instead

```
$("#button").click(function(){})
```

or use js

```
document.getElementById("buton").addEventListener("click", function(){
      });
```